# Unable to import MNIST dataset using MLDatasets package in Julia

Tags: import, julia

I am trying to get the MNIST dataset in Julia using the MLDatasets package via the following commands in a .jl file:

```
using MLDatasets

dataset_train = MNIST(:train)
dataset_test = MNIST(:test)
```

This is what's indicated in the [MLDatasets documentation](https://juliaml.github.io/MLDatasets.jl/stable/). However, I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Module are not callable
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ c:\my\julia\file\...
```

For some reason Julia is interpreting MNIST to be a module. It is worth noticing that this *exact same code* works without problem in a friend's computer, who has the same operating system, and the same Julia version (OS: Windows, x86_64-w64-mingw32; Julia version: 1.8.2).

The MLDatasets package *is* installed and does import correctly with the `using` command. What may be the problem?

Comment: Try starting Julia with `--startup-file=no` flag + instal MLDatasets.jl in a fresh project. If this resolves the issue (it should) then you most likely have an issue with startup file or some outdated version of MLDatasets.jl installed. The current version that you should have is 0.7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you have an older version of MLDatasets installed on your computer. The current version is 0.7.5, while you probably have a 0.5.x version installed. This can happen if there are package conflicts that prevent the latest version of MLDatasets from being installed.

If you're using the default `v1.8` environment to install all packages, conflicts like this are more likely to happen. It's recommended to instead create a separate environment for your project, and install only the packages you need for that particular project in that environment.

Older versions of MLDatasets had `MNIST` as a sub-module rather than as a type, which is the reason for this particular error message.

You can compare your environment's status (`] status`) and the one in your friend's setup. `] status --outdated` can also help you see which particular package is causing the issue here. But I would suggest just keeping your base Julia environment (`v1.8`) minimal, uninstalling packages except the ones that you need to be available everywhere (eg. IJulia). See also the ["Creating your own projects"](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/environments/#Creating-your-own-projects) section of the Pkg documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. As a note, `status --outdated` yielded nothing, but `status --outdated -m` showed the outdated packages. Thank you very much!